# AWS ELB to target one virtual host

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 Instance which is having multiple virtual hosts and serve different websites on different domains. (Let say ABC.com, DEF.com, XYZ.com)

For one specific domain let say ABC.com, its running on HTTP. I have been given free credit from AWS. Now I want to run this ABC.com on https without spending any money.

So I have decided to use ELB as it will come with a free SSL. And I want to target that to ABC.com on my EC2 instance.

I know that with ELB I can target to my instance or my IP. Is it possible to target just one virtual host somehow as this website is not my primary website on a server?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/04/elastic-load-balancing-adds-support-for-host-based-routing-and-increased-rules-on-its-application-load-balancer/

Comment: Do you require to run only one virtual host on https and other are on http?

Comment: Just one ABC.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ELB is using Listeners. Every listener has:
inbound port - in which you can connect to the ELB
target port - the host on the machine you transfer traffic to

If you're ABC.com can use a different port (let's say 8081) than DEF.com, XYZ.com it will be possible to create a listener that listens on port 443 - SSL and configured to send the traffic to port 8081.

Comment: I noticed this that i can configure it for a different port yesterday. i will give it a try today. thumbs up:)

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially achieve this via `Application Load Balancer` using `Host Based Routing`. Different Target Groups can listen on different ports (HTTP / HTTPS).

[Host-Based Routing Support for AWS Application Load Balancers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/%20%20Host-Based%20Routing%20Support%20for%20AWS%20Application%20Load%20Balancers)